# Is there a sass tool for Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a tool like Sass for Javascript? 
To be more specific:

A tool that allows the user to include multiple javascript files via a special syntax and watch for any changes on the files included. Once a change occurs on one or more of those files, the tool should concatenate and compress the files and ideally do some error checking along the way. The results should be included in a single file.

I'm looking for a tool that runs in the background while I'm coding, **not** a server or client side tool like [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) or less.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) but you need to compile oyur .coffee to make a .js

Comment: Is there way to make coffeescript watch for changes in multiple .coffee files and then if a change occurs, to recompile them and join them in one file? I tried `coffee  --join www/js/cstest.js --watch --compile _javascript/*.coffee` and it doesn't work

Comment: Something like this may be : coffee --join project.js --compile src/*.coffee

Comment: The power of stackoverflow :p

Comment: Unfotunately the solution [link] works only on linux machines, and I need a way to run this on my Mac.

Comment: `coffee --join project.js --compile src/*.coffee` doesn't watch for changes

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `coffee --join project.js --compile src/*.coffee` will compile and join the files but it only runs once. I need this command to run automatically everytime there's a change in the files joined